# Why are formatting options sometimes unavailable when editing styles?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

Sometimes when editing specific **Styles** in Microsoft Word 2010, certain formatting options will be unavailable.

For example, while I'm able to adjust any formatting option for the **Normal** style...

[image: Normal formatting options]

...options for ***Paragraph***, ***Tabs***, ***Frame***, and ***Numbering*** are unavailable for **Subtle Emphasis**:

[image: Subtle Emphasis formatting options]

**Why are some formatting options unavailable when editing certain styles? What can I do to make these options adjustable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Word distinguishes between character styles and paragraph styles (plus some linked styles that can be both). Subtle Emphasis is an example of a character style (as indicated by the "a" next to the name). Formatting options that affect a whole paragraph don't apply to character styles.

You wouldn't, for example, apply a first-line indent, numbering, a tab, or a frame to just one character in a paragraph; those are characteristics of the entire paragraph.

Comment: Can I change the **Style type** or make a duplicate style with a different type?

Comment: No, you can't change the style type for Word's built-in styles, but you can always define your own styles to meet your needs.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by creating a new Style with the type **Paragraph**, which has all formatting options available for editing.